# Do RBCs need oxygen?

Tags: cell-biology

How do our red blood cells (RBCs) get oxygen? Do they even need it? They have no nucleus and no organelles, so I think they don't need it.

Comment: Their cytoplasm contains hemoglobin, a protein that carries oxygen. Here is a quote from wikipedia :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_blood_cell                                  ..................   " Erythrocytes consist mainly of hemoglobin, a complex metalloprotein containing heme groups whose iron atoms temporarily bind to oxygen molecules (O2) in the lungs or gills and release them throughout the body. "............

Comment: the energy for RBC is from glycolysis, so I think they don't need oxygen. At least, for the energy they used.

Answer (score 4):

> Erythrocyte metabolism is unique in that the mature erythrocyte
>   contains no mitochondria and therefore no Krebs cycle! Instead the
>   energy needs of the RBC are met largely (95%) by anaerobic glycolysis
>   in the two pathways: Embden-Meyerhof + Hexose-monophosphate.

[image]

+

[image]

[Virginia University source](https://www.med-ed.virginia.edu/courses/path/innes/nh/energy.cfm)